# How to count syllables for affricates

Tags: syllables

I was reading about [readability tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flesch%E2%80%93Kincaid_readability_tests) and it says

> The sentence "The Australian platypus is seemingly a hybrid of a mammal and reptilian creature." scores 37.5 as it has 24 syllables and 13 words.

Word count:

```
 1    2          3       4     5     6   7     8 9   10    11    12
The Australian platypus is seemingly a hybrid of a mammal and reptilian 

  13
creature.
```

Syllables count:

```
 1   2   3   4    5  6   7   8  9   10  11 12 13  14  15 16 17  18  19  20  21 
The Aus tra lian pla ty pus is see ming ly  a hy brid of a  ma mmal and rep ti

22 23  24  25 26
li an crea tu re.
```

I think that 22 and 23 are making diphtongue  so they should be counted as one and 25 is an affricate vowel

so.. why do I count 25 instead of 24?

Comment: Whether _-lian_ is one syllable or two depends on the word, and on the accent of the speaker. You have made it one in _Australian_ and two in _reptilian_.

Comment: The numbers 24 and 13 total 37, not 37.5. I don't understand where the fraction comes from.

Comment: @JasonBassford the formula comes from the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make 24 you would count the syllables like this:

```
1   2   3    4   5   6  7   8  9   10   11 12 13 14   15 16 17 18
The Aus tral ian pla ty pus is see ming ly a  hy brid of a  ma mmal

19  20  21  22  23   24
 nd rep til ian crea ture.
```

I think it's arguable whether the **-ian** is one or two syllables though.

Probably depends on dialect/accent as Colin mentions in comments.

Some would pronounce it *yun* - Aust-rail-yun - which is how the counting above must be doing.
Others would pronounce it *ee-un* - Aust-ray-lee-un - I would pronounce it like this as a native BrE speaker.

Perhaps this is a BrE/AmE thing?
(Thinking of Indian usage in *western cowboy* films = Ind-ee-un/Ind-yun)